# How to inject an Orika FactoryMapper impl using Google Guice?

Tags: guice, orika

Using [Google Guice](https://github.com/google/guice), how do I inject an implementation of [Orika](https://code.google.com/p/orika/)'s MapperFactory?

private MapperFactory mf = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();

i.e. the default constructor is not accessible and you need to use the builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Module, use bind() to register the built instance:

```
bind(MapperFactory.class).toInstance(new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build());
```

or use a @Provides method:

```
@Provides
public MapperFactory mapperFactory() {
   new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
}
```

with the first approach, you get a singleton, so every time you inject a MapperFactory, you get the same instance, in the second case, every time you inject, you get a freshly built copy.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jan. I could not get the #bind attempt to work for some reason I couldn't fathom - generates NullPointerException - but the @Provides annotation works just fine!